# Restore database from bak and ldf files

Tags: sql-server, database, ldf

I just created database from an old bak file and need to recover database to latest version but I don't have recent backups or mdf file but only ldf file. 
How can I recover DB from from only ldf file?

Comment: Do you need to recover transactions from the log file?

Comment: This might help: https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-sql-server-database-using-only-a-transaction-log-file-ldf-and-old-backup-files/ . Surprised it didn't come up on your google search.

Comment: @ADyson does that work without any other data or file besides the LDF? From what I know of SQL, the logfiles don't really contain any data, but I'd be happy to hear that I'm wrong...

Comment: @Sander I haven't tried it. Was really just pointing out that the OP didn't appear to have done a great deal of thinking about the problem before dashing a question off.

Answer (score 1):

A LDF file is a log of all transactions made on the database. As it doesn't contain any data itself, it's not possible to recover a database with only the log file. You can use a log file for database recovery, but only in combination with the data itself.